# what is the meaning of "map" from map function?

Tags: dictionary, terminology

I'm happy to use "map function" in python for parallelized calculations.
such as below.

```
dask_datafram.column.map(target_function)
```

But I don't understand why the name is "map". Map is kind of drawing of land surface.

does it initial? initial of what?

please someone who know the meaning answer the question.

Comment: Please don't use unrelated tags. This has nothing to do with .NET's Task Parallel Library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Map" is also a synonym for "function" in the mathematical sense: something that sends an input to an output.  You should be able to find it in any English dictionary.  It can also be used as a verb for the process of transformation: "map each element to its square".

The word "map" for a geographic drawing is related, in that it also "maps" each point of the real terrain to a point on the paper map, or vice versa.

It is not an acronym.